# Confusion over type of character array elements

Tags: c

I am struggling with the type of elements of a C character array.

```
char get_final (char *num_str)
{
    int len = strlen(num_str);
    char val;
    val = num_str[len-1];
    printf("the number is %s\n", num_str);
    printf("the length is %d\n", len);
    printf("the last digit is %s\n", val);
    printf("the last digit is %s\n", num_str[len-1]);
    return val;
}


int main() {
    char num[4] = "123";
    int last;
    last = get_final(num);
    printf("final: the last digit is %d\n", last);
}
```

When I compile this, I get a warning on the print of the last digit in the function that the format %s expects a char, but that I'm giving it an int.  But I've declared the variable val as char, and I'm assigning it an element from a character array.  So why the integer type complaints?

When I run the code, it segfaults at this same point.

How do I fix this?

Comment: When the error message says "an int", it refers to the `char` that you passed in. The reason it says "an int" is because of the *default argument promotions*.

Comment: Also, the warning message about %s will say that it expects `char *`, not "a char". The stars are important in C :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
printf("the last digit is %s\n", val);
printf("the last digit is %s\n", num_str[len-1]);
```

with

```
printf("the last digit is %c\n", val);
printf("the last digit is %c\n", num_str[len-1]);
```

By putting `%s` in the `printf`, you're saying you want to print a string (0-terminated array of characters pointed to by a `char *`), not a character. But both `val` and `num_str[len-1]` are characters, so you should use `%c` instead.

Answer (score 3):

`%s` expects a null terminated string. `val` is a char so that is a single character and not null terminated.

The `printf` will interpret `val` as a pointer to a null terminated string but since `val` is probably not a valid pointer you get undefined behaviour and likely a crash.

Comment: Nit: `%s` expects a `char *`, which points to the beginning of a 0-terminated string.

Answer (score 0):

The `%s` conversion specifier expects its corresponding argument to have type `char *`, and that the argument points to the beginning of a 0-terminated string.

Both `val` and `num_str[len-1]` have type `char`.  You're getting the segfault because `printf` is interpreting the character values you passed as *addresses*.  Instead of printing `1`, it's looking for a string beginning at address `0x00000031`, which is not a valid or readable address, hence the segfault.

To print out a single character value, use the `%c` conversion specifier.